# How can we get the variable value from script tag of HTML response using javascirpt?

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the value of g_listData from the following HTML response (Received this HTML response from FetchAPI request)

```
<html>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">......</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">......</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

       var g_deferData= "testdata";

       var g_listData = {"wpq":"","Templates":{},"ListData":{ "Row" : [
           {
            "ID": "85018",
            "FileLeafRef": "read only"
           },
           {
           "ID": "85091",
           "FileLeafRef": "completed"
           }
         ]}
       }

    </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You can't have backslash in a variable name.

Comment: You're trying to get the JavaScript from another HTML file using the Fetch API? May I ask why?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier, I got this HTML response from an API request, I would like to use this g_listData in UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try JSON.parse

```js
const data = `<html>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

       var g\_deferData= "testdata";

       var g_listData = {"wpq":"","Templates":{},"ListData":{ "Row" : [
           {
            "ID": "85018",
            "FileLeafRef": "read only"
           },
           {
           "ID": "85091",
           "FileLeafRef": "completed"
           }
         ]}
       }

    <\/script>
    </body>
 </html>`
 
 const div = document.createElement("div")
 div.innerHTML=data;
 let g_listData = div.querySelector("script").textContent.split("g_listData =")[1]
 console.log(JSON.parse(g_listData))
```